# Integral tending to an integral for $\pi$

Tags: integration, pi

I am examining:

$$\int_0^1 (1-ax)^{1/2} dx$$

If we differentiate:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left[\dfrac{-2(1-ax)^{3/2}}{3a}\right]$$

we get to the function in the integral. The idea now is consider various values for $a$, for example $a=1$ but more specifically $a=x$.

Only thing is that I am fairly sure I'm doing something wrong, because I can't see how the integral is going to return $\pi$.

Comment: if you are going to substitute $a=x$ you must do it before you differentiate. ( or else include $\frac{da}{dx}$)

Comment: @WW1; that's exactly what I thought, but Hardy and Wright 'Introduction to the Theory of Numbers' use a very similar technique in Ch. 19 on Partitions numbers (Rogers-Ramanujan especially) and seem to get away with it.

Comment: When you write $\int_0^1 (1 - a x)^{1/2}\; dx$, you are implicitly stating that $a$ is **not** a function of $x$.  If you want it to be a function of $x$, you should write $\int_0^1 (1-a(x) x)^{1/2}\; dx$.  Of course with $a(x)$, you can't use the same integration method that you could with $a$ being constant.